# Passport JWT alway returning "Unauthorized"

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I really didn't want to ask this question as I can see there are so many others in the past however I have lost many hours and none of the previous questions I came across had my answer.

I am always returning `Unauthorized` when trying to use a JWT.

The requested payload even returns and I am able to find the user within the system and console log them.... so I'm just not sure where or why this is failing.

The function in questions:

```
passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET
}, function(jwtPayload, done){
    const o_id = new ObjectId(jwtPayload._id);
    console.log('payload received', jwtPayload);
    return User.findOne({"_id" : o_id}, (err, user) => {
        console.log("user: ", user)  // < --- this is logging out fine
        if(user){
            return done(null, false)
        } else {
            return done(null, false)
        }
        if( err ){
            return done(err, false)
        }
    })
}))
```

I have tried:
`fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt')`
&
`fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('bearer')`
as well.

I've tried my Authorization token as `bearer <Token>` , `JWT <token>` , `BEARER <token>` and `jwt <token>`.

I'm trying to understand it more, I fail to get why my console log for the User return works however I still return an unauthorised response despite all information being presented.

I feel like I am missing something really silly but just can't see what it is. Please help.

Comment: `return done(null, user)` inside `if(user)`

Comment: I've since tried that and failed. I'm convinced the problem is the way I pass the web token, I've checked the secretkey and made sure they match and they do as well.

Comment: remove `return` infront of User.find , if you can find `user` then it means ur jwt is fine .

Comment: Ok yes, that means its failing... still non the wiser as to why....

Comment: err, so can you get `user` object or not ? in your question it says it is loging . So I thought it is logging out a user object.

Comment: No, after removing the `return` it is now failing, which leads me to believe its down to the token in the Authorization header... or its down to the way I'm trying to extract it

Comment: well. log the oid and manually find user in your mongodb first to check.

Comment: @feiiiiii, its working. I miss read an earlier comment from yourself and have since corrected my mistake. Thank you for your time on this. It was down to the return statement not returning `user`

Comment: @feiiiiii, its working. I miss read an earlier comment from yourself and have since corrected my mistake. Thank you for your time on this. It was down to the return statement not returning `user`

Comment: i guess you need to put check for err first and also that err block will never get executed as else statement will handle everything.